# Will Emacs --batch run in cron will hang when require user input?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs, cron

I have a job in crontab that requires emacs --batch but if the file is currently open it requests (s, p, q) to (steal, quit, etc...) which is fine if this file is being edited to not run the script but I want to make sure it kills the cron running script so it's not sitting in the background taking up memory. I have the output set to go to a log file so I can see this happening but no way to tell whether the script was terminated even though asked for user input.

Does cron terminate these scripts and how to check the PID to make sure?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, cron redirects standard input to `/dev/null`.  I tried running `emacs --batch foo.txt --eval '(insert "a")' < /dev/null` while having foo.txt open and modified in a running Emacs, and it printed the question but exited without waiting for a response.  I would expect it to behave the same under cron.

Comment: Yes that does seem to work but if I specify an output file in cron via (> ~/foo.txt) does this mess up the standard input and do I need to specify it manually? I would guess not since (> is for output but couldn't find anything talking about standard input to /dev/null in cron. Thanks

Comment: Also, do you have emacs 24?? Seems on my machine with emacs 24 (other machine has emacs 23.3) to not work properly. It hangs at the question.